# How to call a function when a button is clicked 10 times in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, loops, dart, button

How can I call a method when a button is clicked 10 times. Here is the code for button.

```
NextQuestionButton(
              onClick: () {
                if (answerWasSelected) {
                  _nextQuestion();
                } else {
                  return;
                }
              },
            )
```

Comment: you can add a counter to the button and increase it's count on click then apply logic that when count == 10

Comment: you can add a counter to the button and increase it's count on click then apply logic that when count == 10                      

`
int answerWasSelected =1;


NextQuestionButton(
              onClick: () {
 setState(() {
    answerWasSelected++;
  });
                if (answerWasSelected==10) {
                  _nextQuestion();
                } else {
                  return answerWasSelected;
                }
              },
            )
`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a count variable at parent stateful widget.
And increase count variable when button is clicked and check whether count is over than 10.
If count is over, excute method and reset count.

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
}

class _ParentWidget extends State<ParentWidget> {
   int buttonCount = 0;

   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return ...

          NextQuestionButton(
              onClick: () {
                buttonCount += 1;
                if (answerWasSelected && buttonCount > 9) {
                  buttonCount = 0;
                  _nextQuestion();
                } else {
                  return;
                }
              },
            )
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a counter to the button and increase it's count on click then apply logic that when count == 10

```
int answerWasSelected =1;


NextQuestionButton(
              onClick: () {
 setState(() {
    answerWasSelected++;
  });
                if (answerWasSelected==10) {
                  _nextQuestion();
                } else {
                  return answerWasSelected;
                }
              },
            )
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a counter for your button and when count is getter than 9 then make the count 0 and call your method.

```
    class YourScreen extends StatefulWidget {
}

class _YourScreen extends State<YourScreen> {
   int countOnButton = 0;

   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(

     body:     NextQuestionButton(
              onClick: () {
                countOnButton += 1;
                answerWasSelected && countOnButtoon > 9 
                 ?  _nextQuestion()
                 :  print("methed not working") ;
               
              },
            )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that counts 10 times before executing your own one:

```
Function counter(Function function) {
  int count = 0; // Initialize the count variable

  // Define your function inside the closure
  int increment() {
    function.call();
    count++; // Increment the count
    return count; // Return the updated count
  }

  // Return the increment function
  return increment;
}
```

then pass your function to the counter in initState =>

```
late Function myFunction;
  
@override
void initState() {
  myFunction = counter(() {
    if (answerWasSelected) {
      _nextQuestion();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

Now just call myFunction in `onClick`

```
onClick: () {
  myFunction();
},
```

each time you call it, it will call the `increment` function that is defined in `counter` which will increment the count and once its value is over 10, will implement your function